# R: Temporary File Limit in Foreach Loops

Tags: r, foreach, raster, temporary-files, r-raster

Does the foreach package in R only deal with temporary files up to a certain size?

In my code I try to cut subsets out of a large raster dataset using polygons. The smaller and medium size regions that I extract via `crop` and `mask` are all computed and written to a new raster file (`writeRaster`). The biggest regions in my list, however, do not go through - even if I let the process run for many hours. I remember to have done it once using `for` loops. Any ideas why `foreach` loops do not work here? I always experienced `foreach` as much faster and more efficient than the `for` alternative.

Going back to a `for`-strategy is not an option since it cannot be parallelized.

Comment: Did you try to run the "extraction" of just one of the "big" regions outside of the loop and see if it works/how long does it take? Asking because it seems strange that this is a "foreach" issue. Seems more likely to be a memory/IO time issue.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. You appear to be right. Any ideas how I could overcome the memory/IO time issue?

Comment: No matter how I set it up. The last step always fails. Rasterizing the polygons first or splitting them into smaller regions and merging the smaller masked pieces back together always gets stuck in the final step, i.e. obtaining a big raster file for the entire region.

Comment: it could help if you could share an example of the code you are using. Currently it is not very clear to me what you are trying to accomplish: just cropping the raster and masking it?

Comment: Exactly. Just cropping the raster and masking it. The resulting raster files will be used for other tasks, which are unrelated to the mentioned problem.

The intuition is quite easy. Load a larger raster file, cut smaller pieces out of it using polygons and save those smaller pieces as separate raster files. There is nothing fancy about it.

Comment: Few things: 1) How "Big" is "Big"? I mean, are we speaking of Gigabytes or what? 2) Are the files on your machine, or are you working on a network/NAS? 3) How are you saving the results in writeRaster? Specifying an output format and dataype (e.g., tiff with compression) may strongly reduce output files dimensions.

Comment: 4) Are you doing first mask and then crop, or vice versa? I'd definitely suggest cropping first, then masking the cropped file! Finally, if you are willing to do  some beta testing, you could try the crop_rast and/or mask_rast in this package: https://lbusett.github.io/sprawl/ which could give you some boost in speed by parallelizing some tasks and using vrt files (it's currently under heavy development, but could be useful).

Comment: 1) Each of the larger raster files is around 700 MB large. 2) I tried both, i.e. save the files on my local machine and run the code locally or save the files on an external Linux cluster and run the code on it non-interactively. 3) As an ouput format I chose tif which is also the input raster's format. 4) I crop first and mask afterwards. Thanks for highlighting that new package. I will try to implement it into my code.

Comment: Strange. They are not so big. What is the dimension of the "failing" cropped subsets? And what about data type?

Comment: The biggest region's cropped object appears to be larger than the initial raster dataset in terms of memory space and amounts to around 1.6 GB. The data type is tif and documents pixels saved in a longitude-latitude format. The mask functions time consumption increases non-linearly with region size - i.e. expanding a small area by a specific amount enhances computational time by much less than an enlargement of an already big area by the same quantity. And for the largest regions the mask function gets stuck entirely.